# Mail reaches SMTP Server but isn't delivered to Exchange?

Tags: exchange, smtp, windows-server-2012-r2, outlook, exchange-2013

I recently setup my own Exchange and SMTP Server on a virtual memberserver. Now if I send a mail (with my .net script) it reaches and passes the SMTP Server but it doesn't show up in my Outlook inbox.

Neither the script nor anything else causes an error.

The SMTP-Log is fine as well:

```
12:59:58 192.168.1.12 HELO - 250
12:59:58 192.168.1.12 MAIL - 250
12:59:58 192.168.1.12 RCPT - 250
12:59:58 192.168.1.12 DATA - 250
12:59:58 192.168.1.12 QUIT - 240
```

Do I miss some component or do I need to connect the Exchange and the SMTP somehow special?

Comment: Exchange has it's own built in SMTP server, so if you installed an SMTP server separate from Exchange, then it is probably interfering with Exchange.

Comment: @Patrick this could be it! So the "Send Connector" is the exchanges own SMTP? This would make things way much easier..

Comment: Send Connector is responsible for sending messages out.  Receive connector is responsible for receiving messages in.  It could be that Exchange and whatever SMTP server you installed are both trying to listen on port 25.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exchange has its own built-in SMTP server.  You don't need to install a separate one.

[Send Connectors](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj657457(v=exchg.160).aspx) are used for sending mail out to the internet.

[Receive Connectors](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa996395(v=exchg.160).aspx) are used for receiving mail.

Comment: I was tempted to upvote this just because I have seen how often people use two layers of SMTP servers for incoming emails and screw up the behavior in the process. But eventually I decided this answer need a bit more detail before I am going to upvote it.